# Dynamic Div Tags in a While Loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, while-loop

I have a while loop that populates 4 div tabs (in one parent div) with PHP.

I also have a copy-to-clipboard script to copy text from a P tag. Unfortunately, this function works only if the tag and button have a unique Id.

So my question is this:
How do I assign a sequential Id to my looped P tags? In the sense that I want the first set of tabs in the first populated div to have Ids 1,2,3,4, and the next one to have 5,6,7,8...and so on.

Here is the HTML in the PHP loop:

```
<div id='content' class='tab-content'>
   <div id='navpills-1' class='tab-pane active'>
      <p id='text'>Text to be copied to clipboard.</p>
      <button id='jsbtn' class='btn jsbtn' onclick='copyToClipboard('p#text')'>Copy</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script I'm using to copy text from the P tag to the clipboard:

```
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(element) {
      var $temp = $("<textarea>");
      var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n")).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should not need to use an ID just to make the function work. The button will fire the `event` and from that you can identify the element to be copied quite easily using parent/sibling selectors

Comment: Add the event handlers the _proper_ jQuery way, not using inline attributes. `$('.jsbtn').on('click', function() {...});` Then you have access to the clicked element using `$(this)` - so you can use `$(this).parent().find('p').html()` to go from the button to the parent div, look for the `p` element in there, and gets its content. The IDs on the button and the paragraph can be completely removed then.

Comment: There is also a better API now for copying text to / from the clipboard - [see MDN for details of the Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

Comment: Thank you Professor Abronsius & CBroe for your answers! @Cbroe...could you please write this out for me? What should I put in the button and then in the script? I'm relatively new to PHP, but I don't know anything about Javascript/jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not committed to using jQuery then you can easily accomplish your goal with some fairly basic, vanilla Javascript. The [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) provides the modern solution for copying text (& other things) to & from the system clipboard.

In general working with IDs can become troublesome as they need to be unique within the DOM so where the same functionality needs to be applied to multiple it items you must try to do what you were initially hoping to do - assign sequential IDs or some other such solution and reference that ID in the function call. This does not scale well and better options exist.

The following uses no ID attributes anywhere - instead the event handler assigned to each button uses the `event` to identify which element was clicked ( invoked the handler ) and from that node it is possible, given that you know the DOM structure, to find other nodes of interest. In the code below the `event.target` refers to the button - from there we find it's parent and from that parent we find the specific `P` element whose content is to be copied. The method suggested by @CBroe does this using jQuery methods - something I'm not familiar with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Basic Clipboard Copy Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='tab-content'>
           <div class='tab-pane active'>
              <p class='copy'>Text to be copied to clipboard.</p>
              <button class='btn jsbtn'>Copy</button>
           </div>
           <div class='tab-pane active'>
              <p class='copy'>Some other text to be copied to clipboard.</p>
              <button class='btn jsbtn'>Copy</button>
           </div>
           <div class='tab-pane active'>
              <p class='copy'>Guess what...more text and not an ID in sight</p>
              <button class='btn jsbtn'>Copy</button>
           </div>
           <div class='tab-pane active'>
              <p class='copy'>And the final Paragraph and final chapter and final word.</p>
              <button class='btn jsbtn'>Copy</button>
           </div>
        </div>
        
        <textarea cols=100 rows=10></textarea>
        
        <script>
            document.querySelectorAll('button.jsbtn').forEach( bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{

              const pttn=/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
              const paragraph=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('p.copy');
              const textarea=document.querySelector('textarea');

              // writeText copies text to the clipboard
              navigator.clipboard.writeText( paragraph.innerHTML.replace( pttn, String.fromCharCode( 10 ) ) )
                .then(
                  ()=>{
                    /* 
                       All good... and to illustrate reading this copied text... 
                       readText - reads from the clipboard
                    */
                    navigator.clipboard.readText()
                        .then( text=>{
                            textarea.value=text;
                        })
                  },
                  (e)=>{console.log( 'error: %s',e.message )}
                )
            }));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...you are a genius! Thank you so very much for taking the time and effort to provide the code and solution to my problem! I have one final request - if you see my sample code, it has a 'Regex' variable in it, which I used to ensure paragraph spacing when copying from the P tag. (The text is saved with break tags in the DB, so that it displays nicely when I fetch it.) When I copy the text to the clipboard, I want all the formatting to clear, except for the paragraph spacing. It worked earlier with 'Regex'; tried, but can't get it going in your script. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Made a small change to the above: Checned `textContent` to `innerHTML` so that the regex would work and used the ascii character for a linebreak rather than the string `\r\n` - think it works as expected.

Comment: Once again, @Professor Abronsius, you are a genius! It works like a charm! Thank you so much for making my life easy and for your time and effort. Really appreciate it! :-)

Comment: perhaps you'd like to accept the answer/+1 etc?